# Do patterns on the ground prevent snow?

Tags: animal-crossing-new-leaf

I just finished placing patterns on the ground all around my town in *Animal Crossing: New Leaf*. I was wondering though. When it snows, will there be no snow on the ground because of the patterns? If so, will I be able to make snowmen still?

Answer (score 1):

There will be no snow on top of the patterns (and so you will not be able to make snowmen unless you use snow from uncovered ground), but if you remove the patterns once winter comes there should be snow underneath your patterns given that the ground has not been worn bare of grass.

In other words, if your entire town has been covered with patterns and you keep them once winter rolls around, you'll be able to build snowmen if you erase some of them.